# Is there a chance to prove this sequence to be right?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Can anyone please, set me on right path to prove this ?

We have Real numbers $a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots,a_n$. Then, $M = \frac{(a_1+2a_2+3a_3+\ldots+na_n)}{n}$.
Prove there exists $i \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ such that $a_i \leq \frac{M}{i}$.

I would be really grateful if anyone could at least help me how to solve this, thanks in advance.

Comment: consider b_i =  i * a_i  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose instead that $a_i > \frac{M}{i}$ for all $i \in \{1,...,n\}$. We will show this is not possible (this strategy is called proof by contradiction).

If $a_i > \frac{M}{i}$, then $ia_i > M$ for all $i$. Then $$M = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n ia_i}{n} > \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n M}{n} = \frac{nM}{n} = M,$$ which is clearly not possible. Therefore, there must exist some $i$ such that $a_i \leq \frac{M}{i}$.

Comment: I never made the assumption that $\sum ia_i \geq \sum a_i$. Notice that my answer is still valid for negative $a_i$.

Comment: Didn't you?  You claim... Oh, I see.... your are right.  Never mind..... Awwkkkk!  I misread the entire question!  I read it as proving there is an $a_i$ so the $a_i \le \frac M{\color{red}n}$.... which is not true if the $a_i$ may be negative..... So ... yeah, you are absolutely right....